Bookmarklet to prepend Address bar string
I need to prepend window.location.href in place.
Use case:
Expedite single-webpage tasks by actively updating the Address bar for the User.
UX:

Address Bar displays Location.
User clicks Bookmarklet.
Bookmarklet updates Location to knownString/Location.
Bonus: Browser automatically posts new Location for User.

Example:
Original URI: http://domain1.tld1/default.htm
Modified URI: https://subdomain.domain2.tld2/http://domain1.tld1/default.htm
Hours of fruitless searches and tweak fails of appending/swapping suggestions have me beat.

What have you tried? As far as I can tell, this "just works".

What is your question? What have you tried? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Have you tried: document.location.href = "https://subdomain.domain2.tld2/" + document.location.href?

I didn't include any "what I've tried" b/c I don't know how to do anything, truly. I didn't track my pile of failures lest I pollute the data well with nonsense and waste everybody's time. Cheers and glad tidings.

This should do what you're looking for:
javascript:window.location.href="https://subdomain.domain2.tld2/"+window.location.href


Perfect. Thank you!
